# How do I save from VI to a pipe?

Tags: pipe, vi, buffer

I've seen lots of ways to redirect input from stdin to VI, but I'd like to redirect VI to save to a pipe rather than a file. For example, I'd like to pipe VI's entire pipe buffer to another text editing program, such as kate. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about plain vi. But in Vim, you can write a buffer (or portions of a buffer) to an arbitrary external command via stdin, like `:w !my_external_command`

The help does not mention this being a Vim-specific command, so it may also be available in vi. If you're actually using Vim after all and not just vi, then see `:help :w_c` for details.